# Finding optimal solution to the utility function

Tags: optimization, problem-solving, nonlinear-optimization

I would like to find a solution to the following problem:

---

I have the following utility function:

\begin{equation} 
U(x,r)=\alpha\frac{x^{1-r}-1}{1-r}-(1-\alpha)(x-0.5)^2,
\end{equation}
subject to  $ x\in [0,1], \alpha\in [0,1], r\neq1 .$

I want to maximize the function w.r.t. $x$.

The first order derivative is the following:

\begin{equation} 
U^{'}_{x}(x,r)=\alpha x^{-r} -2x(1-\alpha)+(1-\alpha). 
\end{equation}

I can not find the solution to the equation
\begin{equation} U^{'}_{x}(x,r)=0 \end{equation}

In the end, if there is no analytical solution, I would like to know the sensitivity of the optimal solution w.r.t. to changes in $r$.

Comment: You can't get a closed solution for $x(r)$ but you can for $r(x)$. From this you should be able to understand the sensitivities.